# Java mismatch between String and String[]

Tags: java, string

I'm using Java to implement the Apriori algorithm but one problem exists.

```
ArrayList<String> l1=new ArrayList<>();//L1
...
ArrayList<String[]> lk1=l1;//Lk-1
```

Then it warns that: cannot convert from `ArrayList<String>` to `ArrayList<String[]>`. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: How do you *want* it to convert a list of strings to a list of arrays of strings?

Comment: You're probably going to want to use Collections in favor of String units/arrays of units, since the algorithm you are trying to implement involves set operations (such as set-union).   I'd recommend ArrayList<Set<String>>, etc.

Answer (score 5):

They're different types.  Ignore the collection and just look at the underlying type.

```
   String str = "This is a string.";
   String[] array = str;
```

These are two different types, unconvertable, so as T for the collection, the collections are then unconvertable.  Very basic concept here.